# Any set of Lebesgue measure zero can be represented as the following countable union?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $X$ be a bounded subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of Lebesgue measure $0$. Then $X$ may be represented as a countable union of pairwise disjoint sets $X_n$, such that measure of the closure of each $X_n$ is still $0$. Is this right?

Comment: That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Can you give a counterexample?

Comment: @Dekay At the moment, no. I'm thinking about it.

Answer (score 4):

That is not correct. A set with the quoted property must be of first category. But it is known that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the union of a zero set and a set of first category (cf [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971177/is-mathbbr-is-the-union-of-a-negligible-and-a-meager-set/971194#971194).), while $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself is not of first category.

Comment: +1. Nice answer.

Comment: Note that such a set is constructed in chapter 1 of Oxtoby’s book “measure and category “

Comment: Thanks, this solves my question perfectly.

Comment: @Dekay: Omitting the requirement that the sets $X_n$ are pairwise disjoint (which I think is superfluous, but I haven't given this any thought), one can consider 4 types of "small" sets, each of which forms a distinct [$\sigma$-ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-ideal) of sets: measure zero, first category, simultaneously measure zero and first category, subset of a countable union of closed measure zero sets. **(continued)**

Comment: The first two [are orthogonal $\sigma$-ideals](https://mathoverflow.net/a/43502/15780) (hence in a strong way the third is a proper subcollection of each of the first two), and the fourth (what you're essentially dealing with) is a proper subcollection of the third. This last result means that there exists a set that is both measure zero and first category that cannot be covered by (i.e. a subset of) a countable union of sets of the type you're considering, which incidentally [are exactly the discontinuity sets for a Riemann integrable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/870108/13130).

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro: A very informative comment, thank you!